# Audio Recorder is not able to write to external SSD

Tags: pulseaudio, filesystem, ssd, audio-recording, sound-recorder

I noticed this peculiar issue where when I specify the path for storing the audio recordings using the Audio Recorder to an external Samsung T5 SSD, then it tells me that it cannot write to the file path. It works as expected on my internal HDD though.

[image]

I don't think I have any permission issues because I can copy paste files to my external SSD without any issues. I can also programmatically create files on the external SSD using a Python script - I did that for a sanity check.

Is there a way to make the Audio Recorder directly write to the external Samsung T5 SSD?

Comment: If this is the Snap version, then you'll have containment issues, meaning the USB device will be non-writable without some extra steps. If this was installed via an apt repository, then you may need to verify there isn't an AppArmor rule blocking writes 

Comment: I installed this via apt

Comment: @Matigo How do I "verify there isn't an AppArmor rule blocking writes"? Moreover, whats the mitigation for that?